# Adding a subcategory to a PropertyGrid property from a unchangable class

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I have an existing class, which contains properties similar to this one:

```
private int _someprop = 6;

[Display(Name = "SomeDisplayName", Order = 0, Description = "Description", GroupName="GroupName")]
[GridCategory("Parameters")]
public int SomeProp
{
get { return _someprop ; }
set { _someprop = value; }
}
```

I would like to have all of these properties displayed in a PropertyGrid, with the addition of a subcategory class for each one, which contains 3 properties - min, max and step (numeric values). Having a subcategory class with boolean and enum values will also be great. The issue is that the original class, which contains the 'SomeProp' property should not be changed in any way, since it is referenced directly from another program. The other requirement of this scenario is that all of the subcategory properties should also be accessible.

This is a screenshot of the expected result:

http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/5862/hfox.png

Is there any way to achieve this ?

**Edit:**

The idea is to set the values from the property grid. The scenario is the following:
I have a property grid with list of parameters. Lets say that the parameter is of type int. I would like to be able to optimize this parameter. This means that the user should be able to input a start value (min), end value (max) and a step value to the main property grid. From there I need to retrieve the user input values for min, max and step, and create a list of variations.

An example will be:
If the user inputs min = 10, max = 20, step = 2, then I should be able to retrieve those values in the code behind and create a list of possible inputs for the main property (which will be 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20). Then using this list I can make the optimization logic.

The initializing values of min, max and step should be as follows:
min = main property default value, max = main property default value, step = 1. So basically all values will be coming from the main property default value (which is 6 in the code snippet). From there user should be able to change the min, max and step properties. In that case I do not care if the user is able to change the main property (6) or not, since I will need all the variations between min, max with the particular step.

Comment: This is all possible - custom type-converters and type-desciption-providers can be supplied at runtime. However, it is unclear to me where the 3 values are coming from here... Can you clarify?

Comment: Let me rephrase that. I need a wrapper of 'SomeProperty', which contains a class with 3 different properties (min, max, step) as well as the original 'SomeProperty'. The other issue is that the class, containing 'SomeProperty' will be different, so the list of properties is unknown before the run-time.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example that I can use as a starting point? i.e. that shows where the various values would be coming from?

Comment: I added additional information to the original post. I think maybe the hardest part of this issue is explaining it.

Comment: Which values ? Min, max and step are user defined and they come from the property grid. SomeProp has a default value of 6 (private int _someProp = 6;). What I learned so far is that I probably need code generation to create a wrapper of each property, which contains min, max and step. Then bind this wrapper to the property grid.